# Powershell - delete old folders but not old files

Tags: powershell, backup

I have the following code to keep on top of old folders which I no longer want to keep

```
     Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue| 
      Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } |
       Remove-Item -Force -EA SilentlyContinue
     Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue| 
      Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and (Get-ChildItem -Path 
       $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer }) 
       -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -EA SilentlyContinue
```

It deletes anything older than a certain number of days **($limit)** including files and folders.
However, what I am after is ONLY deleting old folders and their contents.

For example, a day old folder may have file within that is a year old but I want to keep that folder and the old file. The code above keeps the folder but deletes the file. All I want to do is delete folders (and their contents) within the root that are older than the **$limit** else leave the other folders and content alone.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well look at this bit:

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue| 
  Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -ge $limit } |
   Remove-Item -Force -EA SilentlyContinue
```

It's basically saying "everything not a folder and older than specified is removed". So your first step is to remove that.

The second part is just deleting empty folders, you can keep it as-is or you could add to the Where statement to include the CreationTime:

```
 Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force -EA SilentlyContinue| 
  Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit -and (Get-ChildItem -Path 
   $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt $limit }) 
   -eq $null } | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -EA SilentlyContinue
```

The second Where statement returns a list of files and folders newer than $limit, and only deletes the folder if that is null.

Comment: Please forgiver my ignorance, I'm not a coder! So I remove the first line and it doesn't delete files anymore.  However the 2nd line doesnt delete old folders as they're not empty.  What I need is how to delete the non-empty old folders.

Comment: Umm... How do you intend on deleting folders but not the files in them?

Comment: OH wait so you want to delete a folder only if the folder AND its contents are over the limit. Right, gimme a sec.

Comment: Yes, sorry, probably not being clear.  Want to delete old folders and their contents.  New folders left alone even if their contents are old.

Comment: Okay, changed `!$_.PSIsContainer` to `$_.CreationTime -ge $limit` - full detail in answer

Comment: Thank you I'll give it a go and see if I can get it to work.  Cheers for the effort.