# Delete folders older than 10 days but NOT files

Tags: cmd, command-line, windows-10

I need to delete old backup folders that are inside different folder and that are older than 10 days. The problem is that there are also some INI files that can't be touched by the script.

For some time I was using this line given below. I can't use it on the new backup folder, because it will also remove the INI files. I found a topic which describes this procedure using Powershell
[Powershell - delete old folders but not old files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936490/powershell-delete-old-folders-but-not-old-files)

Here is my code:

```
ForFiles /p "E:\Logs" /s /d -30 /c "cmd /c del @file"
```

Is there a way to make it work using Windows CMD?

Comment: Are you saying that a directory should be deleted if it is older than 10 days and does not contain any .ini files of any age?

Comment: No, I want to delete folders older then 10 days (that are inside this directory) and leave the files. I can attach a screenshot later on if you want.

Comment: All files in a deleted directory will also be deleted.